# Как получить данные в php из $.post

Tags: javascript

Как получить значения name, phone, email в feedback.php?

```
$(".modal-order-master__form").submit(function(event) {
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.find('input[name="name"]').val() == "")
    {
        $.noticeAdd({
            text: 'Представьтесь, пожалуйста.',
            stay: false
        });
    }
else if ($this.find('input[name="phone"]').val() == "")
    {
         $.noticeAdd({
            text: 'Как с Вами связаться?',
            stay: false
        });
    }
else if ($this.find('input#agreement1').prop('checked'))
    {
        var postForm = {
            'name'  : $this.find('input[name="name"]').val(),   //Имя
            'phone'  : $this.find('input[name="phone"]').val(), //Телефон
            'email'  : $this.find('input[name="email"]').val(), //
            'page'  : $this.find('input[name="page"]').val()
        };

        $.post( "/core/inc/feedback.php", {'value': postForm, 'action': 'order'}, function( data ) {
            $this.fadeIn(1000).html('<p class="send_ok" style="color: #000;font-weight: bold;"><center>Ваша заявка принята, ожидайте мы скоро вам перезвоним</center></p>');
        });
    }
else 
    {
        $.noticeAdd({
            text: 'Вы должны дать согласие на обработку персональных данных и на условия политики конфидициальности',
            stay: false
        });
    }

event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

Сточки зрения безопасности рекомендую использовать **filter_input**, там Вам и проверка и значение по умолчанию

Для примера

```
$options=array('options'=>array('default'=>0, 'min_range'=>0, 'max_range'=>999));
$page=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);
```

[Подробнее на php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Возвращает нулевое значение

Comment: Что возвращает print_r($_POST) или var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

```
$POST['value']['name'];
$POST['value']['phone'];
$POST['value']['email''];
```